# while including another page in php codeigniter the parent page not loading

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

i am doing a project in codeigniter, all the pages are done using mvc, the codeigniter framework. i have done a few pages in plain php and kept it in the root file. like the following pages:
library.php
database_connection.php

the index page is done using the framework, and i tried including the library.php file as below:

```html
<?php


// Start Session
session_start();

// Application library ( with ShopingCart class )
require __DIR__ . 'library.php'

$app = new ShopingCart();

$products = $app->getProducts();

?>
```

at the top of the index page.

library.php starts like below:

```html
<?php

// load database connection script

include("database_connection.php");

/*
 * Tutorial: PHP MySQL Shopping cart
 *
 * Page: Application library
 * */

class ShopingCart
{



    protected $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = DB();
    }
```

now the problem is when i am loading the index page, its not even loading showing the following error:

> This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

i think its because i am trying to include the file in the page, how can i get rid of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http error 500 stands for a server error.

You have a syntax error here

```
require __DIR__ . 'library.php'
```

your forgot `;`

Comment: its not a syntax error, i correctd it ystrday itself.. the page is blank